# Check convexity of any function in R

Tags: r, math

I am supposed to check whether a function is convex or not within a given interval.

I am using the formula with lambda. Function f is convex if:

[image: Formula]

This is the function I wrote:

```
isConvex <- function(FUN, x1, x2, lambda) {
    if (!is.function(FUN))
        return(errorCondition("Argument FUN is not a function."))

    if (x1 > x2 )
        return(errorCondition("Argument x1 needs to be smaller than x2."))

    if (!(max(lambda) == 1 && min(lambda) == 0))
        return(errorCondition("Argument lambda needs to be a sequence from 0 to 1."))

    return (FUN( lambda*x1 + (1-lambda) * x2 ) - lambda*FUN(x1) + (1-lambda)*FUN(x2) <= 0)
}

isConvex(somefunction, -1, 1, seq(0,1,.01))
```

The function should return either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the convexity of the function, however I get a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s.

For example, `isConvex(exp, 1, 3, seq(0,1,.01))` should return `[1] TRUE`.

According to my task, lambda is supposed to be a sequence.

Comment: You're applying `FUN` to the vector of `lambda`s here (and returning it), so you will end up with a vector. Perhaps you need additional conditions of some sort? For instance, you apply `FUN` to the sequence of `lambda`s, and if any one of them is true, then `FUN` is convex (at that value of `lambda`), and otherwise not.

Comment: Don't you need the inequality to be true for all lambda between 0 and 1?  If so, you should `return(all(FUN(...)... <= 0))`, which will give you a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` value.

Comment: @AndrewGustar I think that's the idea, but the formula doesn't return just `TRUE`s or `FALSE`s, though. If I got a vector with just `TRUE`s or `FALSE`s it would be easy for me to check, but mostly there are a few elements of the vector which are of the opposite logical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is convex if the inequality applies for all lambda between 0 and 1, so you don't need lambda as an argument in your function.

Also, there is a mistake in your inequality - the last `+` should be a `-`.  The inequality should be `f(Lx1+(1-L)x2) <= Lf(x1)+(1-L)f(x2)` - i.e. the function should be below the interpolating straight line between `x1` and `x2`.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)

So I think you need to modify your function as follows (I have ignored the error checking lines)...

```
isConvex <- function(FUN, x1, x2) { #don't need lambda as an argument
   lambda <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
   test <- FUN(lambda * x1 + (1-lambda) * x2 ) - lambda*FUN(x1) - (1-lambda)*FUN(x2) <= 0
   return(all(test))
}

isConvex(exp, 1, 3)
[1] TRUE
```

Actually, to prove convexity, you need to verify the inequality for all combinations of `x1` and `x2` in the range you are interested in, so it is not as straightforward as this (there might be a 'kink' between the end-points that still satisfies the inequality). An alternative, and perhaps more robust approach, would be to test for a positive second derivative.  You could do this by replacing the second line of the function with

```
test <- diff(diff(FUN(lambda * x1 + (1 - lambda) * x2))) >= 0
```